# Exercise about annihilators.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a vector space and let $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ be
>   a basis of this $4$-dimensional space.
>
> We define $F=\{f\in V^*|f(\text{Span}(v_1+v_2))=0\}$.
>
> **1)** Is it true that $L= \text{Ann(Span(}v_1-v_2+v_3,2v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4)) \subset F?$
>
> **2)** Prove that for $v \in V$, $v_3+v_4\in \text{Ann}(F\cap \text{Ann}(v)) \iff v\in \text{Span}(v_1+v_2,v_3+v_4) \wedge v \notin \text{Span}(v_1+v_2)$

My solution:

*1)* I'll say that $L \subset F \iff v_1+v_2 \in \text{Span}(v_1-v_2+v_3,2v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4)$ so the answer is **no** but I'm not really sure about this one.

*2)* It is known that: $\text{Ann}(F \cap \text{Ann}(v))=\text{Ann}(F)+\text{Ann}(\text{Ann}(v))=\text{Ann}(\text{Ann}(v_1+v_2))+\text{Ann}(\text{Ann}(v))=\text{Span}(v_1+v_2)+\text{Span}(v).$

From this we can easily say that if $v\in \text{Span}(v_1+v_2)$ clearly we have that $v_3+v_4 \notin \text{Span}(v_1+v_2)$. Otherwise we have the thesis.

Is it a nice solution? Are there wrong passages or errors? Thanks in advance for your help. If you want to propose another solution I'll be glad to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $^o$ denote the annihilator. For $(1)$, consider $f \in V^*$ defined on the basis $\mathcal{B}$ as:

$$f(v_1) = f(v_2) = -1\\ f(v_3) = 0\\ f(v_4) = 3$$

$\DeclareMathOperator{\span}{span}$Then $f(v_1-v_2+v_3) = f(2v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4) = 0$ so $f \in \big(\span\{v_1-v_2+v_3, 2v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4\}\big)^o$, but $f(v_1+v_2) = -2\ne 0$ so $f \notin F$.

Thus, $L \nsubseteq F$.

For $(2)$, I wouldn't throw isomorphisms around so lighly. First of all, assume that $V$ is finite-dimensional.

Let $\phi : V \to V^{**}$ be the canonical isomorphism, $\phi(x) = \hat{x}$, where $\hat{x} : V^* \to \mathbb{F}$ is defined as $\hat{x}(f) = f(x), \forall f \in V^*$.

You correctly concluded that $\big(F\cap \{v\}^o\big)^o = F^o + \{v\}^{oo} = \{v_1+v_2\}^{oo} + \{v\}^{oo}$.

$\fbox{$\implies$}$ Assume $v_3 + v_4 \in \{v_1+v_2\}^{oo} + \{v\}^{oo} \subseteq V^{**}$. By this is actually meant:$$\hat{v_3} + \hat{v_4} = \widehat{v_3 + v_4}\in \{v_1+v_2\}^{oo} + \{v\}^{oo}$$

Since for $M \leq V$ holds $M^{oo} = \phi(M)$ (and thus $\span\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}^{oo} = \span\{\hat{x_1}, \ldots, \hat{x_n}\}$):

\begin{align}\hat{v_3} + \hat{v_4} \in \{v_1+v_2\}^{oo} + \{v\}^{oo} &\implies \hat{v_3} + \hat{v_4} \in \phi(\span\{v_1+v_2\}) + \phi(\span\{v\})\\
&\implies \hat{v_3} + \hat{v_4} \in \span\{\widehat{v_1+v_2}\} + \span\{\hat{v}\}\\
\end{align}
This implies $\hat{v_3} + \hat{v_4} = \alpha(\widehat{v_1 + v_2}) + \beta \hat{v}$, for some $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}$.

By linearity and bijectivity of $\phi$ we conclude:
$$v_3 + v_4 = \alpha(v_1 + v_2) + \beta v$$

If $\beta = 0$, it would imply $v_3 + v_4 = \alpha(v_1 + v_2)$, which is a contradiction with the linear independence of $\mathcal{B}$.
Thus $\beta \ne 0$ and:

$$v = \frac{1}{\beta}(-\alpha v_1 - \alpha v_2 + v_3 + v_4) = -\underbrace{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}(v_1 + v_2)}_{\in \span\{v_1+ v_2\}} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{\beta}(v_3 + v_4)}_{\in\span{v_3+v_4}}$$

We see that $v \in \span\{v_1+ v_2, v_3 + v_4\}$ and that $v \notin \span\{v_1+ v_2\}$ since the coefficient with $v_3 + v_4$ is $\frac{1}{\beta} \ne 0$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is linearly independent.

$\fbox{$\impliedby$}$ Assume $v \in \span\{v_1+ v_2, v_3 + v_4\} \setminus \span\{v_1+ v_2\}$.

Thus $v = \alpha(v_1+v_2)+\beta(v_3 + v_4)$, for some $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}$, with $\beta \ne 0$.

$$v_3 + v_4 = \frac{1}{\beta}(v - \alpha(v_1+v_2))$$

By linearity of $\phi$ we get:

$$\widehat{v_3 + v_4} = \frac{1}{\beta}(\hat{v} - \alpha(\widehat{v_1+v_2})) = \underbrace{\frac{1}{\beta}\hat{v}}_{\in \phi(\span\{v\})} - \underbrace{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\widehat{v_1+v_2}}_{\in \phi(\span\{v_1+v_2\})}$$

Thus, $\widehat{v_3 + v_4} \in \{v_1+v_2\}^{oo} + \{v\}^{oo}$.

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation! You deserved these points! Thanks again!